# How to resolve a promise inside a return object in rxjs

Tags: promise, rxjs

I'm guessing that there is a different way to structure my code for this, but here is what I'm currently attempting.

'lastSavedPostDate' returns a promise.

How do I get 'lastSavedPostDate' to resolve to a value before my next operation?

```js
var source = Observable.fromPromise(facebookPages)
              .concatMap(page => page)
              .map(page => ({ rid: getRid(page), pageId: page.id }))
              .map(obj => {
                  return {
                    rid: obj.rid,
                    id: obj.pageId,
                    lastDate: lastSavedPostDate(obj.rid)
                  }
                })
```

If I console log my result, I'm getting something back like this.

`{ rid: '#13:0',
  pageId: '18862642',
  lastSavedPostDate:
   Promise {
     _bitField: 131072,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _progressHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined,
     _settledValue: undefined,
     etc...
   } 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var source = Observable.fromPromise(facebookPages)
      .concatMap(page => page)
      .map(page => ({ rid: getRid(page), pageId: page.id }))
      .map(obj => {
          return {
            rid: obj.rid,
            id: obj.pageId,
            lastDate: lastSavedPostDate(obj.rid)
          }
        })
```

you should use

```
  var source = Observable.fromPromise(facebookPages)
          .concatMap(page => page)
          .map(page => ({ rid: getRid(page), pageId: page.id }))
          .flatMap(obj => lastSavedPostDate(obj.rid), (obj, p) => ({rid: obj.rid, id: obj.pageId, lastDate: p}))
```

Comment: Can you explain me this functionality `obj => lastSavedPostDate(obj.rid), (obj, p) => ({rid: obj.rid, id: obj.pageId, lastDate: p})` please?